# Capture touch events in Xamarin.Forms for Android

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

I am creating an app that allows the user to drag and drop to put one image on top of another using Xamarin.Forms.

On iOS I managed to hack together a workable gesture recognizer renderer by creating a custom ContentView and a custom renderer for it, which then attaches native gesture recognizers to itself based on the GestureRecognizers elements. To do that I disable the default EventTracker and implement my own, with overridden GetNativeRecognizer method

in the custom renderer:

```
public InteractiveContentViewRenderer () : base ()
{ 
  AutoTrack = false; 
  events = new InteractiveEventTracker (this); 
}
```

in the custom event tracker:

```
public InteractiveEventTracker (IVisualElementRenderer renderer) : base (renderer)
{
    this.Renderer = renderer; 
}

protected override MonoTouch.UIKit.UIGestureRecognizer GetNativeRecognizer (Xamarin.Forms.IGestureRecognizer recognizer)
{
    var gestureRecognizer = base.GetNativeRecognizer (recognizer);

    if (gestureRecognizer == null) {
// here I find my own native recognizer and return it
    }
}
```

On Android, however, so far I haven't figured out how to achieve the same thing. There's no EventTracker in Android, I think I'll have to implement some Android View for this to work but I haven't figured it out so far.

Has anyone managed to hack together touch events in Xamarin.Forms for Android? I'd like to know at least the basic structure of the hack?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read this: http://blog.twintechs.com/cross-platform-compositional-gesture-advanced-xamarin-forms-techniques-for-flexible-and-performant-cross-platform-apps-part-4

There's a lot about custom gestures in Xamarin.Forms

The source is here: https://github.com/twintechs/TwinTechsFormsLib/tree/master/TwinTechsForms/TwinTechsForms.Droid/TwinTechs/Gestures

Comment: I haven't tried it yet but it looks like what I was after, thank you!

Comment: The first link is dead. Can you update it?